# How to keep a pre-existing table unchanged when using migrations in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, database-migration

I need that Symfony/migration/Doctrine to leave my table untouched. Don't touch her structure at all!

I have a pre-existing table (a legacy database) with the id field defined like this: "id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('configuracoes_seq'::regclass),"

When I define ORM (Doctrine) like this:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"default":"nextval('configuracoes_seq'::regclass)"})
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="configuracoes_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
```

The make:migration changes my table (I don't want it to change) like this:

```
$this->addSql('DROP SEQUENCE configuracoes_seq CASCADE');
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE configuracoes ALTER id SET');
```

---

When I define ORM (Doctrine) like this:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"default":"nextval('configuracoes_seq'::regclass)"})
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="configuracoes_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
```

The make:migration changes my table (I don't want it to change) like this:

```
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE configuracoes ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval(\'configuracoes_seq\'::regclass)');
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE configuracoes ALTER id DROP DEFAULT');
```

---

When I define ORM (Doctrine) like this:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="configuracoes_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
```

The make:migration changes my table (I don't want it to change) like this:

```
    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE configuracoes ALTER id DROP DEFAULT');
```

---

When I define ORM (Doctrine) like this:

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="configuracoes_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
```

The make:migration changes my table (I don't want it to change) like this:

```
    $this->addSql('DROP SEQUENCE configuracoes_seq CASCADE');
```

Does anyone know please how I keep my table unchanged?

Comment: Have you tried getting Symfony to generate the mappings? Check out https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: Yes James, I did it. In this way I prevented the migration from dropping the tables, but did not prevent changes to the table fields.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you do a dump of the PostgreSQL just the structure of the table

Comment: `CREATE TABLE configuracoes
(
  setores text,
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('configuracoes_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT configuracoes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)`

Comment: Did anyone find the solution?